# What to do with alerted variables phpMyAdmin for MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've noticed the following alerted variables in phpMyAdmin

```
Variable    Value   Description
Aborted clients 5    The number of connections that were aborted because the client died without closing the connection properly.
Aborted connects    1.3 k    The number of failed attempts to connect to the MySQL server.
Binlog cache disk use   31   The number of transactions that used the temporary binary log cache but that exceeded the value of binlog_cache_size and used a temporary file to store statements from the transaction.
Created tmp disk tables 2.5 M    The number of temporary tables on disk created automatically by the server while executing statements. If Created_tmp_disk_tables is big, you may want to increase the tmp_table_size value to cause temporary tables to be memory-based instead of disk-based.
Handler read rnd    349.9 M  The number of requests to read a row based on a fixed position. This is high if you are doing a lot of queries that require sorting of the result. You probably have a lot of queries that require MySQL to scan whole tables or you have joins that don't use keys properly.
Handler read rnd next   12.5 G   The number of requests to read the next row in the data file. This is high if you are doing a lot of table scans. Generally this suggests that your tables are not properly indexed or that your queries are not written to take advantage of the indexes you have.
Innodb buffer pool pages dirty  105  The number of pages currently dirty.
Innodb buffer pool reads    8.9 k    The number of logical reads that InnoDB could not satisfy from buffer pool and had to do a single-page read.
Innodb row lock time avg    1.6 k    The average time to acquire a row lock, in milliseconds.
Innodb row lock time max    34.6 k   The maximum time to acquire a row lock, in milliseconds.
Innodb row lock waits   3.9 k    The number of times a row lock had to be waited for.
Opened tables   16.6 k   The number of tables that have been opened. If opened tables is big, your table cache value is probably too small.
Select full join    86 k     The number of joins that do not use indexes. If this value is not 0, you should carefully check the indexes of your tables.
Slow queries    223  The number of queries that have taken more than long_query_time seconds.
Sort merge passes   17   The number of merge passes the sort algorithm has had to do. If this value is large, you should consider increasing the value of the sort_buffer_size system variable.
Table locks waited  551  The number of times that a table lock could not be acquired immediately and a wait was needed. If this is high, and you have performance problems, you should first optimize your queries, and then either split your table or tables or use replication.
```

What should I do?
If you don't want to spoon feed me, perhaps you can advise which 3 take the top priorities and a bit of direction of how I should learn to deal with them?

**Updates on 22/1/2013**
I've dealt with slow queries and since I've restarted my MySQL server, I haven't seen any aborted connections.
Which of the following should be my next focus and why?

```
Variable    Value   Description
Binlog cache disk use   5    The number of transactions that used the temporary binary log cache but that exceeded the value of binlog_cache_size and used a temporary file to store statements from the transaction.
Created tmp disk tables 288.7 k  The number of temporary tables on disk created automatically by the server while executing statements. If Created_tmp_disk_tables is big, you may want to increase the tmp_table_size value to cause temporary tables to be memory-based instead of disk-based.
Handler read rnd    22.5 M   The number of requests to read a row based on a fixed position. This is high if you are doing a lot of queries that require sorting of the result. You probably have a lot of queries that require MySQL to scan whole tables or you have joins that don't use keys properly.
Handler read rnd next   2.1 G    The number of requests to read the next row in the data file. This is high if you are doing a lot of table scans. Generally this suggests that your tables are not properly indexed or that your queries are not written to take advantage of the indexes you have.
Innodb buffer pool pages dirty  1    The number of pages currently dirty.
Innodb buffer pool reads    8.9 k    The number of logical reads that InnoDB could not satisfy from buffer pool and had to do a single-page read.
Innodb row lock time avg    1.2 k    The average time to acquire a row lock, in milliseconds.
Innodb row lock time max    11.2 k   The maximum time to acquire a row lock, in milliseconds.
Innodb row lock waits   631  The number of times a row lock had to be waited for.
Opened tables   2.3 k    The number of tables that have been opened. If opened tables is big, your table cache value is probably too small.
Select full join    17.3 k   The number of joins that do not use indexes. If this value is not 0, you should carefully check the indexes of your tables.
Slow queries    25   The number of queries that have taken more than long_query_time seconds.
Table locks waited  594  The number of times that a table lock could not be acquired immediately and a wait was needed. If this is high, and you have performance problems, you should first optimize your queries, and then either split your table or tables or use replication.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Slow queries.  It reflects on your performance related variables. If it is too high it means your queries have performance issues.
2. Aborted connects. If it is too high over 1 thousands, it is likely your firewall is not set up properly and some worm keeps trying on it. If it is not the cause it means your client fails to connect due to networking problem.

Others aren't that important because you can look at slow queries at first glance.